# Using the results of ROW function as cell reference for another function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

just wondering if this is possible, I haven't seen an example of it.  I have data that I need to match from one excel workbook to another. I have no idea which row the matching data will be in, but I need to use the result of where the data is, as part of another formula.   So far, I've got the ROW part figured out, to be able to find the match in row 16 or 22 or whatever, but how do I blend that with the Column? I looked at INDIRECT and CONCATENATE, but if that's the answer, then I am missing something.

Is it possible to refer to a specific cell using the output of the ROW command?   like =IF(A22=3) but the 22 would come from the ROW function.   So =IF(A&ROW()=3)

Thanks

Comment: It would need to be =IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=3)

Comment: Or, are you trying to reference the column letter dynamically as well?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.   I guess for future-proofing, dynamic column would be great, but right now I just needed the row.      So I guess part 2 of my question though, is how to add this INDIRECT code inline with a bigger formula?     But I think I might have just had a brainwave. :-)     I'll try this.  Thanks

Comment: So weird.  I can't get it to work.  Even just as a test, stripped out all other parts and just used the INDIRECT command by itself, to refer to a cell in another workbook.  It just generates an #REF! error, no matter what.   Even tried 2 fresh new workbooks.  =INDIRECT([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$4)    just gives me the #REF! error

Comment: when you use the indirect function to another workbook, both workbooks must be open in order to do that..., also you need to add quotes like this =INDIRECT("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$4"). Because the way INDIRECT works is that it takes a string like "A1" and turns it into a reference (cell A1)...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the result of the `ROW` function as an argument to the `INDEX` function.  Unlike `INDIRECT`, `INDEX` is non-volatile, and will work on closed workbooks.

eg: To return the contents of `C42` from some other workbook, where 42 is in `A1` where you have the formula that determined the row number:

```
=INDEX('Path\[fileName]worksheetName'!$C:$C,A1)
```

*`Path\` is required if you write the formula when the "other" workbook is closed; not so if you write the formula when the other workbook is open*

Or, you could replace A1 with the formula whose result is the row number you hope to use.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.   I ended up solving the problem, using both INDEX and MATCH as per this link: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match.   Wrapped the whole thing in an IF statement to verify if the dynamically found cell value matched an expected value and then displayed "Y" or "N" depending on the result.